# Calling a Base Class Function through Derived Class Object

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why won't the compiler call the base class function (parameterized one) through the derived class object? The derived class inherits the function from the base class, right?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    int fun()  { cout << "Base::fun() called"; }
    int fun(int i)  { cout << "Base::fun(int i) called"; }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    int fun() {  cout << "Derived::fun() called"; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.fun(5);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I used the scope resolution operator, I got the desired output. Can anyone provide me a logical explanation behind this? Can I still call the base class function (parameterized one) through derived class object? Thanks!

```
int main() 
{
    Derived d;
    d.Base::fun(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derived function `Derived::fun()` *hides* all members with the same name from the base class.  So you can only use the base class member via scope resolution.  To avoid hiding, you can do:

```
class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    int fun() {  cout << "Derived::fun() called"; }
    using Base::fun;
};
```